# Has anyone managed to build any applications with the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn are very cautious of applications using their APIs.  I have tried and failed to get access to them.

Has anyone actually built any real applications with them yet?  If yes, what strategy did you employ to get access to their API?

BTW I am talking about first class value added applications on top of LinkedIn, not just embedding hyperlinks.

Comment: How/Where do you apply for their API?

Comment: I've been wondering this for a while.

Hopefully someone has an answer....

Comment: It seems to be very well hidden / poorly-supported :(

Comment: http://blog.linkedin.com/blog/api/ gives some details but it looks abandoned.

Comment: Why was this marked as subjective?

Comment: By the looks of replies, I think no is the answer. Would I get an up vote for replying NO? :)

Answer (score 7):

The LinkedIn API is now public.

Get access here: http://developer.linkedin.com

Answer (score 3):

We have. our social recruiting startup [matchFWD](http://matchfwd.com) should launch publicly in the next weeks and we make extensive usage of LinkedIn API.

We've forked a python wrapper for the API to make it easy to use : https://github.com/PhilGo20/LinkedIn-Client-Library

The API documentation is a bit off on field selections but their support team on the developer forum is pretty good.

Overall, it's been pretty easy developing around their API and it brings a LOT of value to our product, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I personally haven't, but I know it's possible. Following the link provided by Bobby Jack to the LinkedIn blog, they mention (Jul 25, 2008 entry) that [Xobni](http://www.xobni.com/) has integrated with LinkedIn.

As a longtime Xobni user I can say that it does, indeed, integrate with LinkedIn and does it very well, so yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering the same thing. I tried to gain access to ad a resume section to my website that would be driven off LinkedIn's supposedly "open" API. But I never heard anything back from them. Not cool. Apparently they need to approve your usage of the API. I think someone needs to read to them the definition of the word "OPEN" when they decide to make a claim like that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on the linkedin forum which works right out of the box: http://developer.linkedin.com/message/2185 using the [oauth library](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs)

Comment: Have you even tried the sample? I just downloaded it again; the provided example works, meaning you can authenticate and get your profile back. What else would you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Embedly](http://embed.ly) to pull some data from Linkedin.